# How do you prove that $\theta^Tx + \theta_0$ defines a unique plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to proof that $\theta^Tx + \theta_0$ defines a plane uniquely.

So the idea behind my proof is, assume that a plane has two **different** equations describing it and then show that the equations are actually **not different**.

I was doing it by contradiction. Well, assume that there exists two planes with different equations. i.e.  $\theta^Tx + \theta_0 = 0$ and  $\theta'^Tx + \theta'_0$.

Define a plane as the set of points that satisfies:

$$ \pi = \{ x : \theta^Tx + \theta_0 = 0 \}$$

So the planes are:

$$ \pi = \{ x : \theta^Tx + \theta_0 = 0 \}$$

and

$$ \pi' = \{ x : \theta'^Tx + \theta'_0 \}$$

So consider any point $x \in \pi, \pi'$. Then the following is true:

$$\theta^Tx + \theta_0 = 0$$

$$\theta'^Tx + \theta'_0 = 0$$

by algebra:

$$\theta^Tx - \theta'^Tx + \theta_0 -\theta'_0 = 0$$

$$(\theta - \theta')^T x + \theta_0 -\theta'_0 = 0$$

then I got stuck. I am sure I am very close but I am unsure how to finish off my proof. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand the idea. If you are trying to prove that there is only one plane satisfying this equation, shouldn't you start off by assuming there are two different planes satisfying $\theta^T x + \theta_0 = 0$

Comment: @DimitarM.H. my idea was to show that a planes has a unique equation, so I assumed that there are two different equations for the same plane and then hopefully show that the equations describing the planes are actually the same. But ur idea also sounds good though.

Comment: There are more equations for the same plane. The plane $x+y+z=0$ is also described by $3x+3y+3z=0$.

Comment: @MarkFantini that explains why I got stuck. Do you mind providing a correct proof? Or at least the beginning and see if I can complete it...

Comment: Follow Dimitar's idea. Usually when you want to prove something is unique, you consider two objects which have the same properties and show they are equal.

Comment: So I am not sure what you want to show: You seem to argue for a plane having a unique description with $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ (which is not true, due to the counterexample from Mark Fantini), but you questions asks for the opposite, to show that the equation $\theta x + \theta_0 = 0$ defines a unique plane, which is true.

Comment: @DimitarM.H. yea I know, I was wrong and dum, I will provide the correct proof as an answer later. Thanks guys. :)